# What resistor should I use for connecting seven segment to Arduino?

Tags: arduino, resistors, pullup

I am planning to use Arduino with a 4 digit 7 segment that uses [TM1637 driver chip](https://www.seeedstudio.com/grove-4digit-display-p-1198.html), which has 4 pins, and uses 2 pins for data with i2c protocl.

[image: 4-digit 7 segment]

Here is the code and datasheets:

https://github.com/avishorp/TM1637

Here [it says](http://blog.avishorp.me/2014/03/arduino-library-for-tm1637-display.html) that pull-up resistor is needed. How can I choose appropriate resistors for the 7-segment?

> The second problem also arises from the code snippet above. I2C is
>   wired-and bus, meaning it should never be driven high.When a logic '1'
>   is desirable, the output of the Arduino should be put in
>   high-impedance state allowing the pull-up resistor to pull the line to
>   its high level. This is unlikely to cause an immediate problem, but in
>   the long term it may cause the reliability of the components to
>   degrade.

In some part of the datasheet it says:

```
Electrical character (Ta = -40 - +85℃, VDD = 4.5 - 5.5 V, Vss = 0 V)
Output pull down resistor - Typical ~10KΩ (Test condition K1~K2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I usually use 4.7k, but a 10k should be fine.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please tell more about how can I calculate the appropriate resistor, and how should I place it? Also please suggest appropriatet power. Is 0.25 watt ok?